# Laravel 5.3 - set clear cache on middle not working

Tags: php, authentication, caching, laravel-5.3

I want to prevent the user from clicking back the browsers button. Whenever user logged in and click browser's back button the page redirect back to login which is wrong. I create middleware and register it to the kernel and use it in my route as group but its not working. Here's the code

**MIDDLEWARE**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ClearCache
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->headers->set("Cache-Control", "no-cache,no-store, must-revalidate");
        return $response;
    }
}
```

**KERNEL**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ....

    // CUSTOM MIDDLEWARE GOES HERE
    'clear.cache'   => \App\Http\Middleware\ClearCache::class,
];
```

**ROUTES**

```
<?php

Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function() {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});

Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'clear.cache'], function() {
        Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
    });
});
```

After logging in when user clicks back button it redirects back on login page. Logged out is fine. Any help? :(

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple middleware for one group :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'cache.clear']], function() {
```

But by default Laravel redirects users to $redirectTo defined in your Auth controllers. I don't understand why you are trying to avoid back click.

Comment: imagine when you logged in on facebook and you click back button and then it redirects you back on login page of facebook? isn't that annoying?

Comment: Laravel automatically redirects to the / home ($ redirectsTo) page when you use the guest middleware that forces the user not to be logged in.